# NSButtonCell created programmatically doesn't highlight when clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I wanted to have a button appear in a table view as the first element on the last row instead of the normal data, so I created a subclass of NSTableView and overwrote the preparedCellAtColumn:row: method to generate the desired behaviour on the last row.

```
- (NSCell *)preparedCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row {
    if(row < [self numberOfRows]-1) {
        return [super preparedCellAtColumn:column row:row];
    } else {
        // if we're on the last row, we're going to add the button instead of data
        if(column == 0) {
            NSButtonCell *button = [[NSButtonCell alloc] initTextCell:self.buttonTitle];
            [button setEditable:YES];
            [button setSelectable:YES];
            [button setBezelStyle:NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle];
            [button setGradientType:NSGradientConvexWeak];
            [button setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
            [button setHighlightsBy:NSBackgroundStyleLowered];
            [button setAction:@selector(openAddDialog)];
            [button setControlView:self];
            return button;
        } else {
            NSTextFieldCell *emptyCell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:@""];
            [emptyCell setEditable:NO];
            [emptyCell setSelectable:NO];
            return emptyCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Fortunately, the functionality works--the button appears on the last row, and it calls the openAddDialog selector when it is clicked. There are two visual problems, however:

**1. The button doesn't highlight (press down) when it's clicked.**

<strike>**2. The table selects the row with the button on it when it is clicked.**</strike>

I'm still pretty new to Objective C and Cocoa, so I'm not really sure where to look for the solutions to these. Why isn't the button's setHighlighted method getting called when it is clicked? <strike>What method is called just before the NSTableView selects a row so I can override it and tell it not to select the last row?</strike>

I ended up solving my second question by overriding the selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection: function in my table subclass and simply not passing the last row index on to the super function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to make the column editable in order to activate a UI element inside of it.

BTW, it's usually a bad idea to put some kind of control at the end of a table, especially one that affects the entire table. Tables should be composed of logical repeating units. Putting something unique in a table causes user confusion and can hide functionality. You most likely want to move the button outside the table itself.

Comment: Even if I set the button as editable (and selectable, for that matter) it still doesn't highlight when clicked. What throws me is that the action works fine--so the button is receiving the click, right? If it's catching the click event, why would it not be highlighting?

As far as the control-in-a-table thing goes, it's basically an "Add New Row" button, and I don't have a whole lot of space on the rest of the interface, so it seemed like a logical place to put it. My boss likes it, so I'd be loathe to change it now. :P

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that the button worked otherwise. I'm not sure what the issue is.